# Can I combine two android studio project into a single project

Tags: flutter, kotlin

I am new to programing.
I am currently working on a project A, the project requires some function from project B. project A used flutter as a main display, Whereas project B is completely coded in Kotlin. My initial plan was to used Method Channel to set up a channel from flutter to Kotlin, and copy the codes from project B to project A. However, project B code is too "entangled" and very hard to separate the function I needed. is there a simpler way to combine the 2 project as one? if so, could you explain the process in detail or share the resource
Another this is, If I manage to combine the 2 projects, how would I used the function and valuable in project B (how to declare it in project A)

p.s. project B is a demo project I downloaded from github ( a video calling app )

I tried searching on the internet, but not much came of it. However, there is a similar question posted on this website, but but a bit different from my problem and the answer is a bit confusing for someone who just started app development 2 weeks ago

Answer (score 0):

You must write FLutter codes for a Flutter project. You must use native codes to be able to use the device's functionalities. If you want to transfer screenshots etc. it won't work. You should write the screenshots from scratch with flutter..